# drag and drop of table rows using jquery TableDnD plugin how to make some ros not dragable and save the sorted rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, zend-framework, drag-and-drop

i am using the code i have already implemented the table drag and drop what i want to make is some rows immovable like the top title bar row and the bottom  submit button row how can that be achieved ?

and how to save the sorted list in database by click of a save button ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Initialise the table
$("#table-1").tableDnD();
// DRAG AND DROP ENABLED
```

});

my jquery code is this for dragging ->

i would appreciate any help please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add class="nodrag nodrop" to the row in which you don't want a drag or drop.

And add the following in the ondrop method:

```
$("#table-2").tableDnD({
    onDragClass: "myDragClass",
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
        var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
        var debugStr = "Row dropped was "+row.id+". New order: ";
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
            debugStr += rows[i].id+" ";
        }
        alert(debugStr);
    },
    onDragStart: function(table, row) {
        $(#debugArea).html("Started dragging row "+row.id);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Rob
www.formthis.com

Answer (score 0):

Add two class names to your rows you don't want drag and droppable. tableDnD has these built into its code to prevent drag and drop
In a gridview, this is how I achieve that...

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="dgHead nodrop nodrag" />
<FooterStyle CssClass="NewMaterialEntry nodrop nodrag" VerticalAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```